# why rails rollback unexpected when i try to create a new user in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to complete the signup part,but every time i try to signup at the site the server would show the information that the database had rollback. And i do can't find the new user in the db file.

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-12 17:09:50 +0800
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CkaL2ZiNW8FWXRjPawShiNhQGmP+EHDMgSBbSyihE5E=",         "user"=>{"name"=>"foo1", "email"=>"foo@foobar.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]",   "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
(0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Rendered users/new.html.erb within layouts/application (5.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 24ms (Views: 13.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new 
  end

  def index
  end
  def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @user=User.new(params[:id])
    if @user.save
     #balabala
    else
     render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

new.html.rb:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>



<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>

  <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

  <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>


<span><%= params.inspect %></span> 

<span><%= @user.errors.full_messages%></span>
```

the routes:

```
resources :static_pages 
resources :users
root to: 'static_pages#home'
match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new', via:'get'
```

thanks.

Comment: You should show any validations on your user (or describe what 3rd party gems you are using for user management) and say whether any `@user.errors` are being displayed. It sounds very much like a validation is failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the create action, replace:

```
User.new(params[:id])
```

with:

```
User.new params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
```

To get data passed to the active record model.

---

As for why it failed:

- I guess you have a unicity validation on email
- you pass no email (because wrong params)
- you may already have an empty email in database
- validation fails

Fun fact: it's a good example to have database ensure you have expected data (are null emails really allowed?)

Comment: It throw out this error:`ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError (ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:14:in 'create'`

Comment: this is because you are using strong parameters. I've edited my answer

Comment: It works! Thanks! Null emails are not allowed  `VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence:   true,
  format:     { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }`